# How to fix it **no crontab for root - using an empty one 888**?

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I want to set cron in ubuntu server,but when I run command crontab -e, I see this status or error. no crontab for root - using an empty one 888
How can I fix this.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. It should go away once you save the `crontab` the first time.

Comment: How can I use crontab when I see this waning? Can you help me?

Comment: It should give you an empty editor buffer, you add the new crontab lines you want. When you save it out, root has a crontab.

Comment: What type can I save it? When I use ctrl+y or ctrl+x not working

Comment: It depends on the editor you're using.

Comment: I use default editor

Comment: I don't know what editor that is. Nano? Ed? Ex? Why don't you set the `EDITOR` environment variable to an editor you know how to use?

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8):

I know what you mean, it shows a line "888" when you run command `crontab -e`.
That's because you chose `/bin/ed` as your editor, but you are not familiar with it.

Just `vi ~/.selected_editor` , you'll see it and change the value to `/usr/bin/vi` .

Then run command `crontab -e` again, it will be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your crontab editor has been switched to **ed**. To exit **ed**, press <kbd>Q</kbd> and subsequently <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will quit the **ed** editor.

If you would like to change your crontab editor back to **nano**, use:

```
sudo select-editor
```

This also might be helpful:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Comment: `sudo select-editor` changes the editor for `root`

Comment: EDITOR=nano crontab -e fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This just means there isn't a crontab so it's generating one.

Once it opens, you should be able to save it then the warning won't appear again.
If you're using nano as a text editor (some defaults), you can press Ctrl+X then Y to confirm and it should save/update the crontab.